# Wrapping If statement in switch statement SQL

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, reporting-services

I am trying to wrap my if statement in my switch statement. Can someone show me how please? This is in visual studio 2012.

```
   <ReportName>



                            =Switch(
    Fields!ERROR_CATEGORY.Value= "Tin + Tax Country", "Tin and Tax Country 
    Detail",
    Fields!ERROR_CATEGORY.Value= "Passport No + Issuing Country", "Passport 
    Issuing Country Detail",
    Fields!ERROR_CATEGORY.Value= "Lei", "Lei Detail",
    Fields!ERROR_CATEGORY.Value= "Legal Name Country Incorporation", "Legal 
    Name 
   Country Inc Detail",
   Fields!ERROR_CATEGORY.Value= "Legal Name Country Jurisdiction", "Legal 
   Name 
   Country Jur Detail",
   Fields!ERROR_CATEGORY.Value= "First Name, Surname + Dob", "First Name 
   Surname Dob Detail",
   Fields!ERROR_CATEGORY.Value= "Full Name + Dob", "Full Name Dob Detail",
   Fields!ERROR_CATEGORY.Value= "Company Reg No + Country Inc"
, "Company Reg Country Inc Detail")</ReportName>
```

This is the if statement i want to include in this :

```
 IIf
 (Fields!ERROR_TYPE.Value = "Break", IIf(Fields!ERROR_COUNT.Value &lt;&gt; 
 Nothing and Fields!ERROR_COUNT.Value &lt;&gt; "0", "Underline", "None"), "None")
```

Comment: What happens when you include it?   Do you get some error?   What error?

Comment: i don;t know how to wrap it, i was looking for someone to show me how the following would look with it wrapped inside if possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `IIF()` function returns a single value, so the way you incorporate in into a `switch` function, **or any other code at any time**, is to simply place it somewhere where a value is expected.

So to give a short example, you can take a `switch` like this:

```
switch(
A=1,"1",
A=2,"2"
)
```

And include an `iif` like this:

```
switch(
A=1,"1",
A=2,iif(B=1,"2","two")
)
```